# How to use stack and a queue to generate all possible subsets on n-element set nonrecursively?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, stack, queue, push

---

This is question from Data Structures and Algorithms in Java by Michael T Goodrich and Robert Tamassia. How to do this? Any help appreciated.

This is what I thought, correct me if I am wrong:

> Store elements in Stack. Pop first element and store it in queue and remaining elements in Stack form a subset. Restore the Stack, now pop the second element (pop first in queue, pop second in queue, and push from queue) and the remaining elements in stack from another subset. Similarly pop third element and then fourth. Now, its turn to do the same with two elements and then three elements? Did I misunderstood the question and stretching it too far?

Comment: If I understood your solution correctly, the issue is that you only ever remove elements that are adjacent. So, for instance, let's say you're removing "two elements at a time" on {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}. Then you'd remove {3, 4} but not {2, 4}.

You are right though... since there is a systematic way to pop off the `i`th element then you can use the trivial solution with a bitmask as suggested by Pieter below. But I think it's not the cleanest/intended solution

Answer (score 2):

I have defined the ArrayStack() and ArrayQueue() classes

```
n=[1,2,3,4,5]
st=ArrayStack()
q=ArrayQueue()

q.enqueue(set())

for i in range(len(n)):
    st.push(n[i])


while st.is_empty()==False:
    cur_el=st.pop()
    print('cur',cur_el)
    for i in range(len(q)):
        a=q.dequeue()
        print('a',a)
        q.enqueue(a)
        b=a|{cur_el}
        q.enqueue(b)
        print('b',b)

while q.isempty()==False:
    x=q.dequeue()
    print(x)

OUTPUT
cur 5
a set()
b {5}
cur 4
a set()
b {4}
a {5}
b {4, 5}
cur 3
a set()
b {3}
a {4}
b {3, 4}
a {5}
b {3, 5}
a {4, 5}
b {3, 4, 5}
cur 2
a set()
b {2}
a {3}
b {2, 3}
a {4}
b {2, 4}
a {3, 4}
b {2, 3, 4}
a {5}
b {2, 5}
a {3, 5}
b {2, 3, 5}
a {4, 5}
b {2, 4, 5}
a {3, 4, 5}
b {2, 3, 4, 5}
cur 1
a set()
b {1}
a {2}
b {1, 2}
a {3}
b {1, 3}
a {2, 3}
b {1, 2, 3}
a {4}
b {1, 4}
a {2, 4}
b {1, 2, 4}
a {3, 4}
b {1, 3, 4}
a {2, 3, 4}
b {1, 2, 3, 4}
a {5}
b {1, 5}
a {2, 5}
b {1, 2, 5}
a {3, 5}
b {1, 3, 5}
a {2, 3, 5}
b {1, 2, 3, 5}
a {4, 5}
b {1, 4, 5}
a {2, 4, 5}
b {1, 2, 4, 5}
a {3, 4, 5}
b {1, 3, 4, 5}
a {2, 3, 4, 5}
b {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
set()
{1}
{2}
{1, 2}
{3}
{1, 3}
{2, 3}
{1, 2, 3}
{4}
{1, 4}
{2, 4}
{1, 2, 4}
{3, 4}
{1, 3, 4}
{2, 3, 4}
{1, 2, 3, 4}
{5}
{1, 5}
{2, 5}
{1, 2, 5}
{3, 5}
{1, 3, 5}
{2, 3, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 5}
{4, 5}
{1, 4, 5}
{2, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 4, 5}
{3, 4, 5}
{1, 3, 4, 5}
{2, 3, 4, 5}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

Only half-facetiously:

1. Create the stack and ignore it;
2. Create the queue and ignore it;
3. Output (iteratively) the numbers from 0 to (2^N)-1 in binary form of length N, with leading zeros.

Any required alternate representation of the subsets is easily generated from the binary representation of the generated integers, by interpreting each 1-bit as inclusion, and each 0-bit as exclusion.

Technically this meets the criteria as it (a) creates a stack; (b) creates a queue; and (c) non-recursively generates all possible sub-sets of an N element set. The stack and queue are strictly redundant for an iterative solution, so why they are asked for without any further guidance/constraints eludes me.

Update:

Random access to the input set can be replaced by use of the queue, by treating it as a circular buffer. (Of course, then it cannot be used for anything else.) Either a marker element can be added to the queue to indicate when each cycle is complete, but more natural for the algorithm as presented above is to process N elements at a time, N being known in advance. As each element is dequeued it is processed (added or ignored for the current subset) and enqueued again.

Comment: Your solution assumes you have an indexed collection storing the original elements. I think the point of the problem is doing it just with a stack and a queue. Impractical? Sure. But it's a homework problem.

Comment: @roliu: That sounds good; but how does one restore the original stack non-recursively in order to generate the second, and all subsequent, subsets?

Comment: I'm just responding to this question in my answer above since I can't really format here.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a reasonable solution which was stolen from here: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=96354&sid=e74a29103e9297050680afbba6b72f32&start=40

So the idea is that the Queue will hold the subsets, and your stack will hold your original set. The empty set is a subset of every set and so we initialize the Queue with it. Then, for each element on the stack, we pop it off. Now for each subset on the Queue, we dequeue that subset and enqueue two copies: 1) One without the new element (i.e. the same as the original), 2) One with the new element. The tricky part is keeping track of when you need to pop the next element of the stack (i.e. when you're done with the current element). One way to do this would be checking the entire Queue for a matching set (meaning you've already added this subset you constructed... so stop). But a nice/cleaner way is to use the empty set as a marker.

Basically you have your typical recursive solution:

```
GenerateSubsets(Set set)
{
    if (set == Set.EmptySet)
        return new List<Set>(set);

    var elem = set.Remove();
    var subsets = GenerateSubsets(set);
    // Add all of thew subsets that contain elem (i.e. partition all subsets
    // by whether they contain elem or do not contain elem)
    subsets.AddRange(subsets.Map(subset => subset.Add(elem));

    return subsets;
}
```

And we use the exact same idea where the Queue *iteratively* constructs `subsets` and the original set is stored in Stack.

```
GenerateSubsets(Stack originalSetAsStack)
{
    var queue = new Queue { new Set() };
    while (!originalSetAsStack.IsEmpty)
    {
        var elem = originalSetAsStack.Pop();
        while (true)
        {
            var currSubset = queue.Dequeue();
            // This is key. This is how we know when to start
            // the next iteration!
            // This also assumes that any two empty sets are equal...
            if (currSubset == new Set())
            {
                break;
            }

            var subsetWithElem = currSubset.Clone();
            subsetWithElem.Add(elem);
            // Add back in current subset. This has to be first!
            // for our break to work above
            queue.Queue(currSubset);
            queue.Queue(subsetWithElem);
        }
    }

    return queue;
}
```

To show why this solution stems from the recursive solution. Observe:
We construct the subsets iteratively:

```
-Start with the empty set => ({})
-Take some element from the stack
-Now for each element in the Queue, enqueue two: one with the current
element, and one without => ({}, {elem})
-Now take the next element and do the same => ({}, {elem}, {nextElem}, 
{elem, NextElem})
-Now take the third element and do the same => ({}, {elem}, {nextElem}, 
{elem, nextElem}, {thirdElem}, {thirdElem, elem}, {thirdElem, nextElem}, 
{elem, nextElem, thirdElem})
-...
```

Comment: How is the original set stored in Stack after the first subset is constructed?

Comment: It's not. Bad naming I guess? It begins as the original set, but it shrinks in size as we process elements

Comment: A third storage is required: either a random access to the original set, or random-access to work-in-progress for ALL elements of the powerset. Clearly the first is vastly more performant.

Comment: How does my solution need random-access to the "work-in-progress" powerset. It stores them in the queue... not a list. But you are right that this question is exceptionally poorly phrased. I think this is the intended solution though because they specified specifically that there should be no recursive solution.